# QGIS is shading some polygons with an unexpected darker color

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology

Using QGIS 3.32.0 on a MBP to create a map of Los Angeles parcels in an area of interest.  I have applied a categorized polygon fill symbol to a field I added to the shapefile and for some reason many of parcels are shaded in a darker color than the symbology chosen.  I have applied a 50% opacity and these appear not to use that opacity.  This is not a problem for me but curious whether others have seen this behavior.

All of the polygons appear to be valid.

[image: Snippet of QGIS rendering of parcels with some randomly appearing not to adhere to the opacity or some other issue causing them to be bolder]

Answer (score 3):

Well, color me embarrassed.  The darker polygons have multiple colocated polygons which I need to dig into, but that would answer the darker color for opaque fill.

And I see why - each of these are zoned > R1, so have multiple units each which are represented by their own property polygon.  Now I have to solve for that problem since my analysis is on the area occupied by various types of property...